# How to get the auxiliary equation for a linear differential equation with undetermined coefficients?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am taking a course in Differential Equations and we were shown how to use the auxiliary equation to easily get the general solution for a differential equations with constant coefficients. For example:
$$
y'' - 4y' + 16y = 0
$$
has the auxiliary equation:
$$
m^2 - 4 + 16= 0
$$

However, I wanted to know how one can write the auxiliary equation for a DE with undetermined coefficients. For example:
$$
2x^2y'' + 5xy' + y = 0
$$

Thank you!

Comment: Wouldn't that be nice?

Comment: It is $m^2-4m+16=0$ which has two comolex roots. for the second example, it is non linear and there is no auxilary equation .

Comment: thank you for the answers gentlemen... I thought this was a linear DE... may I ask what makes it non linear @AbdallahHammam?

Comment: I am going to try and solve it how you mentioned @Moo

Comment: @Muaz : the equation if not $m^2-4+16=0$ , but is $m^2-4m+16=0$. The roots are complex : $m=2\pm i2\sqrt{3}$ so that the solutions are $y=c_1e^{2x}\sin(2\sqrt{3}x)+c_2e^{2x}\cos(2\sqrt{3}x)$.

Comment: Instead of linear ODE with *undetermined coefficients*, we speak of [linear ODE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_differential_equation) with *variable coefficients*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clarify the question about linearity :
Both equations

$y'' - 4y' + 16y = 0$

$2x^2y'' + 5xy' + y = 0$

are linear.

For ODEs, linear means linear relatively to $y$ , $y'$, $y''$ even if the coefficients of them are not linear.

To solve $\quad y'' - 4y' + 16y = 0\quad$ change of function :
$$y(x)=c\:e^{m\:x}$$ 
in order to obtain 
$$m^2-4m+16=0$$

To solve $\quad 2x^2y'' + 5xy' + y = 0\quad$ change of function :
$$y(x)=c\:x^m $$
in order to obtain 
$$2m(m-1)+5m+1=0$$

Comment: Thank you so much! But could you please explain how the form $ y(x) = cx^m $ is understood? How does the $ x^2 $ translate to $ m(m-1) $ ? Thanks again!

Comment: Just put $y=cx^m$ into $2x^2y''+5xy'+y=0$ and simplify. You get $2m(m-1)+5m+1=0$ any values of $c$.

Comment: That is perfect. Thank you!